# Algorithmically determined roles based on folder structure

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, pattern-recognition

I have a directory filled with 2000 subdirectories for individual users on a website. In each user directory, there are up to seven different types of folders. Inside those folders, there are several different kinds of files. For instance, you may have:

```
user1/forms/a.txt  
user1/forms/b.txt  
user1/forms/c.txt  
user1/docs/x.txt  
user1/docs/y.txt  
user2/forms/b.txt  
user2/forms/c.txt    
user2/forms/d.txt  
user2/docs/y.txt
```

...and so on, but it's much more complicated than that. What I want to do is lump users together based on roles. For instance, the "Default" role could include a.txt, b.txt, c.txt, x.txt and y.txt, which user1 would have, and then The "Reduced Forms" role could subtract forms a.txt and x.txt.

But the folder structure is a sprawling mess, and it's one of my first tasks at this job to fix it. I'm going to create a web app that generates forms on the fly... but I need to create some kind of role system.

Worse, certain files are renamed slightly so it changes things up a bit.

Is there some kind of algorithm that I can use to determine rough categories for roles? I'm trying to wrap my head around this problem, but really it's a pattern recognition problem which is of course hard to program.

Thoughts on how to approach it?

Answer (score 0):

I think this a not Pattern Recognition problem. you must build your custom access control system. Try to look at role based system, discretionary, mandatory system or bell-lapadula model to get idea from their sample:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell%E2%80%93LaPadula_model

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discretionary_access_control

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandatory_access_control